# How to use IF statement in twig for given use case

Tags: html, if-statement, twig

I am using twig for templating

```
{{ content.field_votre_type_the_profil[0] }} returns "test string"
```

so when i compare it in if statement it not working...
for example

```
{% if content.field_votre_type_the_profil[0] == "test string" %}
    <p>Hey i found the string</p>
{% endif %}
```

I am not getting the "**Hey i found the string**" in output..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the logic, and say:

```
{% if content.field_votre_type_the_profil[0] != "test string" %}
```

If your P tag appears, there is a problem with your value being lost/overwritten somewhere.

If you can't get it to print your html no matter what your logic is: check that your syntax is correct, make sure there are no errors happening with the plugin itself, etc.

Let me know if you've tried anything else, I'll respond with more help.

Try this and tell me what it prints:

```
{% if content.field_votre_type_the_profil[0] == "test string" %}
    <p>Hey i found the string</p>
{% else %}
    <h1>Your variable is being overwritten, or not included for some reason</h1>
{% endif %}

{{ content.field_votre_type_the_profil[0] }}
```

Comment: I have already tried reversing the logic...when i do that i get error like Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected character "!" . I have also tried to use single quotes in place of double quotes..but still not working...my "p" tag not at all printing..and no error is thrown

Comment: I get "Your variable is being overwritten, or not included for some reason"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it..

I had to go one level deeper to do this if calculation.

```
{% if content.field_votre_type_the_profil[0]['#markup'] ==  "test string" %}
```